# What is the difference between textual and symbolic insertion?

Tags: d

[The D language](https://dlang.org/pretod.html) uses "symbolic" rather than "textual" insertion of code. I believe languages like Java and Go also uses symbolic insertion, so it appears to equally apply to languages that compile to native code as it does to interpreted/byte-code languages.

Can someone explain the difference to me?

**EDIT**

The question is about dependencies between different software modules. C/C++ implement this with pre-processor "#include" macros that essentially copy-and-paste the file. This is required so that the compiler knows about the size/alignment of classes, etc. This is "textual" insertion. D/Java/Go/etc don't use textual insertion, but rather symbolic insertion. One of the practical implications of this is improved compilation speed. What I want to know is, how does "symbolic insertion" actually work?

Comment: What do you mean by "insertion of code"? Are you talking about how preprocessor macros work?

Comment: Questions about properties of programming languages would probably be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com. SO is for problems with actual code you're trying to write.

Comment: How is a question about D related to the diferent languages C or C++? Don't spam tags!

Comment: @Olaf, I've edited my question to be more clear. It's only spam tagging if the question doesn't relate to those languages. The link I referenced spefically discussed the include-vs-import usage in d/c/c++.

Comment: @user1420752: 1) It does not change you are asking about D, not the other languages. Just mentioning a language does not justify the tag. 2) As you were informed already, we are not a tutoring/explain the language site. Please either delete this questions and ask elsewhere or as a mod to migrate, if possible.

Comment: As a sidenote: The C standard does not require a compilation phase. In fact there are C interpreters (which is not much of a problem). Your prerequisites are wrong already.

Answer (score 1):

I admit I had to read the question few times to understand it... If I understood it correctly, you wonder what is the difference between what you call "textual" insertion of code in C/C++ with the `#include` directive, and D's `import` statement?

Before I go further, let me tell you that D has (well, kind of) "textual insertion" as well - have a look at the [D's import expression](https://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#ImportExpression).

The main difference between D's import and C/C++ #include comes from the fact that D is a *modular language*. So `import` in D is actually a declaration. Your question is answered in the "[The C Preprocessor vs D](https://dlang.org/pretod.html)" article:

> C and C++ rely heavily on textual inclusion of header files. This frequently results in the compiler having to recompile tens of thousands of lines of code over and over again for every source file, an obvious source of slow compile times. What header files are normally used for is more appropriately done doing a symbolic, rather than textual, insertion. This is done with the import statement. Symbolic inclusion means the compiler just loads an already compiled symbol table. The needs for macro "wrappers" to prevent multiple #inclusion, funky #pragma once syntax, and incomprehensible fragile syntax for precompiled headers are simply unnecessary and irrelevant to D.

Comment: If that's what OP means: That's actually used by all better designed languages, including Pascal, Ada, Modula, Python, etc. C and C++ are more of an exception than normal.

Comment: I wouldn't call the import expression textual insertion in the same sense as the C preprocessor. Even if you mixin(import(file)), it is compiled separately, not just pasted into the source, then the compiled AST node is appended at that location in the source.

Comment: True. I said that simply because import expression loads text and does nothing else. `string txt = import("file.txt");`